# Swift Check for Wifi bug in iOS 14.5 and higher

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS Swift app I'm using this code to check if there is a connection with Wifi available:

```
    static func isConnectedToNetwork(onlyWifi: Bool) -> Bool {
    
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    
    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }
    
    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }
    
    // Only Working for WIFI
    if (onlyWifi) {
        
        let isReachable = flags == .reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .connectionRequired
        
        return isReachable && !needsConnection
    }
    else {   
        // Working for Cellular and WIFI
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)
        
        return ret
    }
}
```

If I check for only a wifi connection, the code returns `false`. This issue is present since iOS 14.5, before that this problem never happened.

Comment: This isn't the right approach anyway. You should use NWPathMonitor and check whether the network is expensive/low data.  Just because a network is wifi doesn't mean that it isn't constrained.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I can find an example of this?

Comment: You can see an example here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/networking/how-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-nwpathmonitor not that there can be issues using it in the simulator so it is best to test it on an actual device